# Non-Nullable becomes Nullable on return

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

I think I've seen this question answered somewhere, but I can't find it and don't remember the answer.

Assuming Nullable-Reference-Types is enabled.

There is a method that returns a `string`. The caller of the method stores the resulting string into a variable. The variable will be Nullable, even if the method's return value is non-nullable.

```cs
static string MyMethod() 
{
   return "Hello World!";
}

public static void Main() 
{
   // result is of type string? here. Hence nullable.
   var result = MyMethod();
}
```

The same does not seem to happen with primitive types, but it does happen reference types, like `object`. Kind of defeats the purpose of NRT for me. I'm  sure there's a reason for this and it's "by design".

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I can print out `result.Length` and `result2.Length` without any warnings.

Comment: How do you observe that the variable is now nullable? Perhaps there is an issue with however/whatever you do to analyze and observe this behavior?

Comment: `result` will be `string?` due to the use of `var` (which is by design, per Matthew's answer), but `result2` certainly will not be -- it's `string`, just as you've specified. `result2 = null` will not compile. Note that static analysis will ferret out that `result` is not actually `null` after the call to `MyMethod`, despite the implicit type, so expressions involving it will not trip warnings. In all cases, NRTs only exist on the language level, not the runtime level, so the underlying *reference* can always hold `null` (forced through `result2 = null!`). This, too, was a design choice.

Comment: Yes, `result2` is definitely NOT nullable. I'll mention that in my answer to make it explicit.

Comment: @JeroenMostert you're right about `result2`. It's not nullable. Might have been a weird hang-up on the static analysis... or just me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is indeed by design.

The meeting notes where this design was chosen are here: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/meetings/2019/LDM-2019-12-18.md#var

To summarise: It was found that people were frequently having to explicitly type the variable rather than using `var` because after assignment from a non-null-returning method, the code went on to assign `null` to the variable.

To quote from the meeting notes:

> At this point we've seen a large amount of code that requires people
> spell out the type instead of using var, because code may assign null
> later.

That is, code like the following was found to be quite frequent:

```
var someVariable = SomeMethodThatDoesntReturnNull();
...
someVariable = null; // or someVariable = someMethodThatCanReturnNull();
```

Note that (as pointed out by Jeroen Mostert) `result2` in your question is NOT nullable because it's explicitly typed as non-nullable. I'm not sure why you think it *is* nullable, but it definitely isn't.

For example, look at [this repro on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3Zf1Ec) and note the warning on line 11.

Comment: Edit: Corrected link to design meeting notes.

Comment: I thought non-nullable is the new default. It being the default seems that there is an assumption that it is the normal case. If that assumption is correct, then the people that want to null something later should have to spell it out, instead of the majority of people using var and expecting things to be non-nullable. Maybe this is the wrong place to post this, but this design choice seems to go against the premise of having non-nullable reference types be default.

Answer (score 0):

In C# 8.0, strings are known as a nullable “string!”, and so the Allow Null annotation allows setting it to null, even though the string that we return isn't null (for example, we do a comparison check and set it to a default value if null.)